# Reference DropDownList selected value from enclosing Form

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm just getting started with MVC5 (from WebForms), and dropdownlist bindings are giving me some fits.

I'd like to get this working using a GET request back to the page, with a selected value parameter. I'm hopeful that I can specify the route arguments in the form itself, so I'd like to reference the DDL's SelectedValue.

```
<p>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Profile", FormMethod.Get, new { id = WHATDOIPUTHERE} )) {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        @Html.DropDownList("ApplicationID", new SelectList(ViewBag.ApplicationList, "ApplicationID", "ApplicationName", ViewBag.SelectedApplicationId), new {onchange = "this.form.submit();"})
    }
</p>
```

I can make it work with a POST form, but that requires a second controller method so I end up with

```
public ActionResult Index(long? id) {
    ConfigManager config = new ConfigManager();

    //handle application. default to the first application returned if none is supplied.
    ViewBag.ApplicationList = config.GetApplications().ToList();

    if (id != null) {
        ViewBag.SelectedApplicationId = (long)id;
    }
    else {
        ViewBag.SelectedApplicationId = ViewBag.ApplicationList[0].ApplicationID; //just a safe default, if no param provided.
    }

    //handle profile list.
    List<ProfileViewModel> ps = new List<ProfileViewModel>();
    ps = (from p in config.GetProfilesByApp((long)ViewBag.SelectedApplicationId) select new ProfileViewModel(p)).ToList();

    return View(ps);
}

//POST: Profile
//read the form post result, and recall Index, passing in the ID.
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult index(FormCollection collection) {
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Profile", new {id = collection["ApplicationId"]});
}
```

It would be really nice to get rid of the POST method, since this View only ever lists child entities.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your GET action method parameter name to be same as your dropdown name.

I also made some small changes to avoid possible null reference exceptions.

```
public ActionResult Index(long? ApplicationID) {

   var config = new ConfigManager();

   var applicationList = config.GetApplications().ToList();
   ViewBag.ApplicationList = applicationList ;

    if (ApplicationID!= null) {
        ViewBag.SelectedApplicationId = ApplicationID.Value;
    }
    else 
    {
       if(applicationList.Any())
       {
         ViewBag.SelectedApplicationId = applicationList[0].ApplicationID; 
       }
    }

    var ps = new List<ProfileViewModel>();
    ps = (from p in config.GetProfilesByApp((long)ViewBag.SelectedApplicationId) 
                                               select new ProfileViewModel(p)).ToList();

    return View(ps);
}
```